# How dividing a number with 5 gives no. of multiples of 5 from one till that number?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

For example 60/5 = 12, which means there are 12 multiples of 5 between 1 to 60. What is the logic behind it ?

Is it the case with only 5 or dividing a number with any particular number x gives no. of multiples of x from one till that number ?

Comment: There are twelve numbers "between" $1$ and $12$...

Comment: Any number. A multiple of $x$ is $k\cdot x$ for some $k\in\mathbb{Z}$. We have - for $x > 0$ - $1 \leqslant k\cdot x \leqslant N \iff 1 \leqslant k \leqslant \frac{N}{x}$.

Comment: It works in general. If $k,n$ are positive integers, to find the number of multiples of $k$ that are $\le n$, divide $n$ by $k$, and if necessary round down to the nearest integer. For example, let $k=12$ and $n=2013$. Then $\frac{n}{k}=167.75$. So there are $167$ multiples of $12$ between $1$ and $2013$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the division algorithm at work. If $n$ and $k$ are positive integers, we know that there are unique integers $q$ and $r$ such that $n=qk+r$ and $0 \leq r < n$. Then $1k, 2k, \ldots qk$ are all less than (or equal to) $n$.

Answer (score 2):

Note that $\dfrac {60}{5} = 12 \iff 60 = \underbrace{12\times 5}_{12\text{ multiples of } 5}$.

In general, if $x \mid n$, then $\dfrac {n}{x} = m \iff n = m\times x$, where $m$ is the number of multiples of x that yields $n$.

Comment: Needs a TU -> +1

Answer (score 0):

A complete list of all the positive multiples of 5 up to 60.
$$1\times 5 = 5$$
$$2 \times 5 = 5 + 5 =10$$
$$3 \times 5 = 5 + 5 +5 = 15$$
$$4 \times 5 = 5 + 5 +5 +5 =20$$
$$5 \times 5 = 5 + 5 + 5 + 5 + 5 = 25$$ 
$$6 \times 5 = 5 + 5 + 5 + 5 + 5 +5 = 30$$ 
$$7 \times 5 = 5 + 5 + 5 + 5 + 5 +5 +5 = 35$$
$$8 \times 5 = 5 + 5 + 5 + 5 + 5 +5 +5 +5 = 40$$
$$9 \times 5 = 5 + 5 + 5 + 5 + 5 +5 +5 +5 +5= 45$$
$$10 \times 5 = 5 + 5 + 5 + 5 + 5 +5 +5 +5 +5 + 5 = 50$$ 
$$11 \times 5 = 5 + 5 + 5 + 5 + 5 +5 +5 +5 +5 + 5 +5 = 55$$
$$12 \times 5 = 5 + 5 + 5 + 5 + 5 +5 +5 +5 +5 + 5 +5 +5 = 60$$
See how they're numbered on the left by the $n$ in $n \times 5$. Can you generalize this?

Comment: The OP asked about the twelve multiples of $5$, not the five multiples of $12$.

Comment: Granted, the OP asked of this would work for *any* number, so maybe it's worth keeping!